# Global sections of holomorphic fibre bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-topology, complex-geometry

Let $P$ be a holomorphic fibre bundle over a closed Riemann surface $\Sigma$, denoted $P \to \Sigma$. Furthermore, I assume that the fibers are diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{CP}^1$.
I am interested in the existence of a global holomorphic section of this bundle.

My idea was to use that fact that this is a projective line bundle over a closed Riemann surface and it therefore arises as the projectivization of a rank $2$ vector bundle $E$, denoted $P=\mathcal{P}(E)$.

Observation: Taking the tensor product $E \otimes L$ with a complex line bundle $L$ does not affect to projectivization, since $\mathcal P(E)=\mathcal{P}(E \otimes L)$.

However, I could not find a reference/theorem to make sure that we can build a global section of $P$ from, say a "special" global section of $E$. Any hints/references for that? Thank you in advance.

Additional thoughts: I was thinking of using cohomology, but that didnt help me for now.

Comment: I’m re-using an argument I saw someone else make on this site: Let $L$ be a large power of a very ample sheaf, then $E \otimes L$ is generated by its global sections… but as $E$ has rank $2$, a generic section of $E \otimes L$ has no zero on $\Sigma$ and therefore works as a global section of $P(E)$.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. How do I make sure this is also a holomorphic section of $P(E)$?

Comment: How could it not be? $E$ minus the zero section projects holomorphically to $P$, no?

Comment: I would have to foster literature a bit for that. This topic isnt exactly my strength, but I still want to try to understand as to when I can count on the existence of holomorphic sections.

Comment: I am really thankful for your hints so far though! Any starting point helps me.

Comment: What do you mean by 'foster literature' and 'hints'? @Aphelli solved the problem fully. Also, you write 'independent of the vector bundle chosen' but this is obviously false.

Comment: I just dont understand the answer yet, since I had no opportunity to study these subjects yet and I came across this in a paper I tried to read. 
So yes, my question might contain an error because I missunderstood something and yes, i cannot understand why Aphellis answer is right without putting in more work.

Comment: Ok, the thing is this: on a nice enough space X, any projective bundle (which is a holomorphic fiber bundle whose fibers are projective space of dimension n) is given by the projectivization of a vector bundle E of rank n+1. Two such projectivizations P(E) and P(E') are isomorphic as bundles over X iff there is a line bundle L such that E' is E tensor L. So it is not 'independent' of which vector bundle you choose.

Comment: Now to answer your question: pick E such that your bundle is P(E). By the previous reasoning, we can tensor E by any line bundle and nothing in your question changes. In particular, tensor by a high enough power of a very ample line bundle (call this L) as per Aphelli's suggestion. The reason for doing this is that E tensor L has lots of non-zero sections by a theorem of Serre. Now E has rank 2 while you're living on a Riemann surface, which is of dimension 1. What happens if you have too many equations and too few variables?

Comment: The last comment shows that *most* sections of E tensor L will never vanish. Now if you have a non-zero vector in a vector space V, it defines a line, hence an element of P(V). Do this fiberwise for a non-vanishing section of E tensor L and use the first comment that P(E) = P(E tensor L). Hopefully this is convincing enough!

Comment: Thank you for breaking it down in more elementary (or complex analysis) terms for me. And yes, now I feel convinced, since this feels within my grasp. Feel free to copy paste it in an answer so I can accept it (if you want to).  
I will also fix the error in my question to avoid confusion for other people reading this question.

Comment: @CraniumClamp would you consider recording that as an answer below?

Comment: If CraniumClamp doesnt, I will do it at some point (probably first week of november), so the question gets the "answered" tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a record of Aphelli's suggestion, as an answer.

Write $ P $ as $ \mathbb{P} (E) $ for a holomorphic rank $ 2 $ vector bundle $ E $ on $ X $. We will use the following theorem of Serre.

Theorem: Let $ X $ be a projective variety and $ E $ a vector bundle on $ X $. Let $ H $ be a very ample line bundle on $ X $. Then there is an integer $ N $ (which depends on $ H $ and $ E $ in general) such that for every $ n \ge N $, the vector bundle $ E \otimes H^{\otimes n } $ is generated by its global sections - For clarification, this means that the global sections restricted to a fiber span the fiber as a vector space.

Remark: The space of global sections of $ E \otimes H^{\otimes n} $ is finite dimensional and for large enough $ n $ as above, this dimension grows asymptotically at the rate of $ n^{\dim X} $. (This is not strictly needed but good to know.)

Noting that a compact Riemann surface is a projective variety, we pick a very ample line bundle $ H $ on $ \Sigma $. Now choose an $ N $ for the pair $ E,H $ according to the theorem. Then $ E \otimes H^{\otimes N} $ has enough global sections. A general global section of the above vector bundle does not vanish on $ \Sigma $ as it is of rank $ 2 $ while $ \Sigma $ has dimension $ 1 $. (For a rigourous explanation of what 'general' means, I recommend reading about Bertini's Lemma)

Pick such a general section $ s $ as above. Note that the fibers of $ \mathbb{P}(E \otimes H^{\otimes N}) \rightarrow \Sigma $ are just projectivizations of the fibers of $ E \otimes H^{\otimes N} $, more or less, by definition. Since $ s $ does not vanish in any fiber, its value in every fiber's projectivization defines a section $ [s] $ of $ \mathbb{P}(E \otimes H^{\otimes N}) \rightarrow \Sigma $.

Finally $ \mathbb{P}(E \otimes H^{\otimes N}) $ is just $ \mathbb{P}(E) = P $ by the remark that tensoring by any line bundle does not change the projective bundle, hence $ [s] $ indeed is a section of $ P \rightarrow \Sigma $ as desired.